# How to make end of list visible?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

The last element in my list is being cut off. I can see from console logs that it's rendering and if I comment out the position from being fixed, I can see the element at the bottom of the list. However, for some reason, I cannot see it when I make the position fixed (the behavior I want the list to have).

File where I render the list (the list is JobFeed):

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div style={headerStyle}>
      <h3>header></h3>
      <ListsHeader state={state} dispatch={dispatch}/>
    </div>
    <div style={listContainerStyle}>
      <JobFeed state={state}/>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

And the styles:

```
const headerStyle: CSS.Properties = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row'
}

 const listContainerStyle: CSS.Properties = {
   scrollBehavior: 'smooth',
   maxHeight: '100vh',
   width: '100%',
   overflow: 'auto',
   position: 'fixed',
   margin: 0
 }
```

The list component:

```
return (
    <ul style ={listStyle}>
      {activeJobs.map(item => {
        return(
          <li key={item.id}>
            <JobCard item={item}/>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
```

And the list style:

```
const listStyle: CSS.Properties = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  listStyleType: 'none',
  listStyle: 'none',
  paddingLeft: '26%',
  height: '100vh'
}
```

I'm using react, typescript, and csstype for the styling.

Comment: Is `<JobFeed state={state}/>` what is rendering your truncated list?

Comment: yes JobFeed renders the list, in which the last one is cut off unless I comment out the position in listContainerStyle

Comment: Seems like a CSS problem and React likely doesn't play much of role here. post the generated html of the list so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that but I will add the list and the style for that

Comment: Use Chrome's developer console. Right click on the list in the browser and hit "Inspect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it was like 200px too short, for the list style I added a marginBottom of 250px and that solved it. Not sure why that happened.